# Ruby test if input is integer

Tags: ruby, regex, if-statement

I have the following function

```
def getValue(x) 
    puts "Key: #{x}"
    if x =~ /[0-9]+/
        puts "x is an int"
    else
        puts "x is a string"
    end
end
```

On getValue(1) it should output "x is an int" but instead I get "x is a string"

Comment: Why not just write `puts x.class = #{x.class}"`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland my goal is to run some expression of x is an int and another expression if x is a string

Comment: That's a different question, whose answer could be `case x; when Fixnum then process_fixnum(x); when String then process_string(x); when Float... end`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left-hand expression must be a `String` to use the `=~` operator with a regular expression. Call `to_s` on `x` before testing against the regular expression:

```
def getValue(x) 
    puts "Key: #{x}"
    if x.to_s =~ /[0-9]+/
        puts "x is an int"
    else
        puts "x is a string"
    end
end
```

Also, method names in Ruby are `snake_case`, so `getValue` should be `get_value`.

Or you could just use `x.is_a? Integer` if you want to check the *type* of the value, not the *string representation*.

Regex advise: As Michael Berkowski mentioned, your regular expression will match a string that has a digit anywhere. You should anchor the pattern between `\A` (start of string) and `\Z` (end of string):

```
\A[0-9]+\Z
```

Even more nit-picking: the `[0-9]` character class is equivalent to the `\d` meta character, so you could do this as well:

```
\A\d+\Z
```

Comment: Also recommend anchoring the pattern with `^$` because it would also match `notanumber99notanumber` as `/[0-9]+/`

Answer (score 3):

Use `is_a?` to inspect the type:

```
def getValue(x) 
    puts "Key: #{x}"
    if x.is_a?(Integer)
        puts "x is an int"
    else
        puts "x is a string"
    end
end
```

Output:

```
irb> getValue(1)
Key: 1
x is an int
irb> getValue("1")
Key: 1
x is a string
```

Comment: Rigid type checking is generally frowned upon in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to test if it can be converted to an integer, not if it is one:

```
def get_value(x)
  puts "Key: #{x}"

  # This throws an ArgumentError exception if the value cannot be converted
  Integer(x)

  puts "x is an int"

rescue ArgumentError
  puts "x is not an integer"
end
```